# MSSQL/MySQL + PHP: Compare two arrays for matching id's where the column names are different as is their location, in separate tables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sql-server

I am using CentOS6, PHP5.6, MySQL5.1, and MSSQL 2008.
Reference key for my databases structures:

- databaseA = MySQL
- databaseB = MSSQL
- tableA    = primary_key and my_key is "code" in the first column.
- tableB    = primary_key is "id" in the first column, and my_key is "sku" in the 3rd column.
- queryA    = grabs rows "where quantity > x"
- queryB    = grabs rows "where selling = Y"

What I need to do is compare the results from both queries and print results where `tableA.my_key === tableB.my_key` and spit back the results from tableB.

Here's my current code:

```
 40   // create arrays for comparison
 41   $queryA_rows = array();
 42   $queryB_rows = array();
 43   while($queryA_row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryA)) {
 44     $queryA_rows[] = $queryA_row;
 45   }
 46   while($queryB_row = mssql_fetch_array($queryB_query)){
 47     $queryB_rows[] = $queryB_row;
 48   }
 49   $result = array_diff_assoc($queryB_rows, $queryA_rows); // compare for differences
 50 
 51   foreach($queryA_rows as $queryA_row){
 52     foreach($queryB_rows as $queryB_row){
 53       if($queryA_row['code'] == $queryB_row['sku'] ){
 54 //      print_r($queryB_row);
 55         print_r($queryA_row);
 56       }    
 57     }
 58   }
```

When I echo the query results by themselves I get what I expect, it's when I try to join (I looked at joining tables but it reads as impossible between two service providers in Google) them for comparison and then get the final results that it fails me.

```
queryA_results = [123, 321, 231, ...]
queryB_results = [456, 546, 321, ...]
diff_ results  = Array ([productcode] => Array (
                  [0] => 4017727
                  [otherid] => 4017727
                  [1] => PLU-TOK
                  [sku] => PLU-TOK)    // looks like it's building a new array from each query result and reassigning the index
```

I looked at creating new arrays where 'code' and 'sku' don't matter and it would look at [0] of each array, but the comparing key I am using is not in the first column of both tables so they wouldn't match that way. I would think I could assign the vale to compare with `$queryA_row['code']` and `$queryB_row['sku']` but that doesn't return anything when they print.

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: `$queryA_rows[] = $queryA_row;` and the same with the 2nd array

Comment: @splash58 that was a typo when I changed the variables for this sample, the actual code reads as such. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: maybe you show sample data of both arrays and the expected result?

Comment: @splash58 I have updated the question with some sample returns.